# How to use datastore api with jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-datastore

I persist time state in viewModel and need to store current state in preferences and load time state again when app is closed and opened again by user. Here is my current code.

ViewModel

```
class TimeViewModel(): ViewModel(){
 private val _time = MutableLiveData<Long>()
 val time: LiveData<Long> = _time
 fun onTimeChange(newTime: Long) {
   _time.value = newTime
 }
}
```

Composable function

```
@Composable
fun Timer(timeViewModel:TimeViewModel = viewModel()){

 LaunchedEffect(key1 = time ){
  delay(1000L)
  timeViewModel.onTimeChange(time + 1)
 }
 val time: Long by timeViewModel.time.observeAsState(0L)
 val dec = DecimalFormat("00")
 val min = time / 60
 val sec = time % 60
 Text(
  text = dec.format(min) + ":" + dec.format(sec),
  style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1
 )
}
```

Comment: you can use Flow. Here is an example [example](https://www.raywenderlich.com/18348259-datastore-tutorial-for-android-getting-started)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using dagger for dependency injection you could create a singleton with your store this way:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object MyModule {

    private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "preferences")

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDataStore(@ApplicationContext app: Context ) :  DataStore<Preferences> = app.dataStore
}
```

then just inject in your viewModels and use it!

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>
) : ViewModel() {

    private val myKey = stringPreferencesKey("USER_KEY")// init your key identifier here

    fun mySuperCoolWrite(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dataStore.edit {
                it[myKey] = body.auth
            }
        }
    }

    fun mySuperCoolRead(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val preferences = dataStore.data.first()
            preferences[myKey]?.let {
                // here access your stored value with "it"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Or just inject in your controller constructor with

```
@ApplicationContext app: Context
```

[here](https://we-launch.com/3-main-steps-to-learn-jetpack-datastore-preference/) you can find more info